# How to create Facebook group using graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I want to create Facebook group using Graph API.

Actually what i want to do: I am having a course module, so when admin add a new course i want to create a group in Facebook with course name.

Can you please help how to create Facebook group using Graph API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but it seems like it is not possible to create "Group" or "Event" via Facebook API. Probably closest option for you is to create a new page or post.

Comment: Correct, it is not possible to create groups via API. Facebook had a product called "App & Game Groups" for a while - those could be created via API, but that has since been removed again.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for you answer.